# Capacitors' working in a circuit

Tags: electrostatics, potential, capacitance, voltage, batteries

Does charge in a capacitor containing circuit stop flowing when the potential of the capacitor becomes equal to the potential of the battery??

Comment: Just to be clear, you are asking about one capacitor connected by wires to one battery, nothing else in the circuit?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is just "yes, obviously, the voltage is zero". The answer below is unnecessarily computational, but I'm keeping it in case someone likes that.

---

**Archived answer**

I'll assume you are talking about an circuit with a capacitor and resistor inside. Then, let $Q$ be the charge, $t$ be the time, $C$ be the capacitance, $R$ be the resistance, $T$ be the time constant, and $V$ be the electromotive force. You must know of the differential equation:
$$\frac{{{\text{d}}Q}}{{{\text{d}}t}} = \frac{{ - Q + CV}}{T}$$

Separating the equation and integrating,
$$\frac{{{\text{d}}Q}}{{{\text{d}}t}} = \frac{V}{R}\exp \left( { - \frac{t}{T}} \right)$$

Since the current is the rate of change in the charge with respect to time, we can rewrite this equation in the following form:

$$I = \frac{V}{R}\exp \left( { - \frac{t}{T}} \right)$$

So, the potential of the battery being equal to the potential of the capacitor simply means that $V=0$, so
$$I = \frac{0}{R}\exp \left( { - \frac{t}{T}} \right)=0$$

So yes, although it will take an infinite amount of time to reach this point.

Answer (score 1):

When you connect a DC-source to the capacitor, the capacitor will "instantly" have a charge which is equal to C*V (with V the voltage of the source, and C the capacitance of the capacitor). 
The current through a capacitor equals:
I = dQ/dt = C*dV/dt

So when a constant voltage is applied, the current will be zero (since there is no change in voltage, dV/dt=0. Actually, dV/dt is a delta function when the voltage is applied (since the voltage is a step function), so there will be a short current pulse).

(When you have a circuit with a DC-source, a capacitor AND a resistor, the capacitor will load smoother with a damped exponential function. Eventually, the charge and voltage will be constant and there will be no current flowing.)

Answer (score 1):

### It depends

[image: Circuits: a capacitor connected in series or in parallel]

Attached in series, then yes once charged, the capacitor represents an open circuit and current ceases to flow.

In parallel current can flow through the resistor which is does *once* the capacitor is charged (to any degree) reaching maximum current when the capacitor is fully charged.

Comment: A very slight EE quibble:  there's no time dependence in either drawn circuit.  As drawn, the voltage across the capacitor is, has, and will be the battery voltage.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Well, there is that. And I though of it just after I uploaded this one. With real wire, of course, there is a little resistance on all paths; thought the time constants are pretty small unless you use a monster capacitor.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You're question is ambiguous as other answers have shown.

(1) if you're thinking of a simple two element circuit with a battery and a capacitor, the capacitor voltage must, at all times, equal the battery voltage.  ***Assuming the battery voltage is constant***, the circuit current will be zero.

(2) if you're thinking of a simple series circuit that includes a battery, resistor, and a capacitor, the capacitor voltage asymptotically approaches the battery voltage.

(3) if you're thinking of something else, you'll simply have to be more specific.

The crucial consideration is this:  the current through a capacitor is proportional to the rate of change of the voltage across the capacitor.

So, to answer the question in general, if the voltage across the capacitor is *constant*, the current through the capacitor is zero.